# Trouble getting access to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner and was starting to learn react router. I made a json server to store a fake api containing a json file of movies. Currently, I have a page that lists just the title of movies in a list These are retrieved dynamically from the json server, not hardcoded in html.

My goal is to click on one of these links for the title and display more detailed info such as description, runtime, genre, etc. This is where i'm having trouble. I can't display the detailed information when clicking the links. When i console.log the object, it's showing the corresponding movie object and its detailed info. However, when I return the information, it's not getting access to the object. I've attached my json.

I've tried changing the fetchMovie variable to contain `get`:

```
const fetchMovie = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/movies/get?id=${match.params.id}`); 
//pass match variable to query json. This returned a 404 error
```

The line that i'm having trouble with is the {movie.title} line. It's not getting access to the movie object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlbFs.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJqu.jpg)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './MovieDetail.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

function MovieDetail({ match })  {

useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovie(); //call fetch function
    console.log(match);

}, []);

const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});

/*const movies = [
    { id: 1, title: 'The Fast and the Furious: Hobbs and Shaw', description: 'Lawman Luke Hobbs and outcast Deckard Shaw form an unlikely alliance when a cyber-genetically enhanced villain threatens the future of humanity.', director: 'David Leitch', year: 2019, budget: '200000000', runtime: '137', rating: 'PG-13', genre: 'Action', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ7PAyCDwEg'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Terminator: Dark Fate', description:'Sarah Connor and a hybrid cyborg human must protect a young girl from a newly modified liquid Terminator from the future.', director: 'Tim Miller', year: 2019, budget:'200000000', runtime: '141', rating: 'R', genre: 'Action, Sci-Fi', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxy8udgWRmo'},
    { id: 3, title: 'Avengers: Endgame', description:'Adrift in space with no food or water, Tony Stark sends a message to Pepper Potts as his oxygen supply starts to dwindle. Meanwhile, the remaining Avengers -- Thor, Black Widow, Captain America and Bruce Banner -- must figure out a way to bring back their vanquished allies for an epic showdown with Thanos -- the evil demigod who decimated the planet and the universe', director: 'Anthony and Joe Russo', year: 2019, budget: '356000000', runtime: '181', rating: 'PG-13', genre: 'Action, Sci-Fi, Adventure', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c'},
    { id: 4, title: 'It: Chapter Two', description:'Twenty-seven years after their first encounter with the terrifying Pennywise, the Losers Club have grown up and moved away, until a devastating phone call brings them back.', director: 'Andy Muschietti', year: 2019, budget:'79000000', runtime: '169', rating: 'R', genre: 'Horror, Drama, Fantasy', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhJ5P7Up3jA'},
    { id: 5, title: 'Ad Astra', description:'Astronaut Roy McBride undertakes a mission across an unforgiving solar system to uncover the truth about his missing father and his doomed expedition that now, 30 years later, threatens the universe.', director: 'James Gray', year: 2019, budget:'87500000', runtime: '123', rating: 'PG-13', genre: 'Adventure, Drama, Mystery', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCNKuB93BA'},
    { id: 6, title: 'Lion King (2019)', description:'After the murder of his father, a young lion prince flees his kingdom only to learn the true meaning of responsibility and bravery.', director: 'Jon Favreau', year: 2019, budget:'87500000', runtime: '119', rating: 'PG', genre: 'Animation, Adventure, Drama', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Raf9bVk75s8'},
    { id: 7, title: 'Rambo: Last Blood', description:'Rambo must confront his past and unearth his ruthless combat skills to exact revenge in a final mission.', director: 'Adrian Grunberg', year: 2019, budget:'50000000', runtime: '89', rating: 'R', genre: 'Action, Adventure, Thriller', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPuhNtG47M0'},
    { id: 8, title: 'Angry Birds 2', description:'The flightless birds and scheming green pigs take their feud to the next level.', director: 'Thurop Van Orman, John Rice', year: 2019, budget:'65000000', runtime: '97', rating: 'PG', genre: 'Animation, Adventure, Comedy', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQJlFpMprl4'},
    { id: 9, title: 'Gemini Man', description:'An over-the-hill hitman faces off against a younger clone of himself ', director: 'Ang Lee', year: 2019, budget:'138000000', runtime: '117', rating: 'PG-13', genre: 'Action, Drama, Sci-Fi', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyJignbSj0'},
    { id: 10, title: 'Joker (2019)', description:'In Gotham City, mentally-troubled comedian Arthur Fleck is disregarded and mistreated by society. He then embarks on a downward spiral of revolution and bloody crime. This path brings him face-to-face with his alter-ego: \"The Joker\".', director: 'Todd Phillips', year: 2019, budget:'55000000', runtime: '122', rating: 'R', genre: 'Crime, Drama, Thriller', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5btyBWXgl44'},
    { id: 11, title: 'Toy Story 4', description:'When a new toy called \"Forky\" joins Woody and the gang, a road trip alongside old and new friends reveals how big the world can be for a toy.', director: 'Josh Cooley', year: 2019, budget:'200000000', runtime: '100', rating: 'G', genre: 'Animation, Adventure, Comedy', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmaLetrWPxQ'},
    { id: 12, title: 'Spider-Man: Far From Home', description:'Following the events of Avengers: Endgame (2019), Spider-Man must step up to take on new threats in a world that has changed forever.', director: 'Jon Watts', year: 2019, budget:'160000000', runtime: '129', rating: 'PG-13', genre: 'Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi', Trailer: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt9L1jCKGnE'},


  ]*/

const fetchMovie = async () => {
    const fetchMovie = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/movies?id=${match.params.id}`); 

    const movie = await fetchMovie.json();

    setMovie(movie); //setstate
    console.log(movie); //object shows up fine here 


};


return (

        <div className="card-movie">
            Test
            <h2>{movie.title}</h2><br/>   **<--not getting access to object**

        </div>
);

}

export default MovieDetail
```

Comment: Has the API and endpoint to give such item info? Did you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you are using a fake API with just a JSON file. This means there is no way to get a part of this JSON and you always have to fetch the entire list of movies and then choose the appropriate one.
You could do that with such a `fetchMovie()` function.

```
const fetchMovie = async () => {
    const allMoviesFetch = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/movies'); 

    const allMovies = await allMoviesFetch.json();

    let selectedMovie = {};
    allMovies.forEach((movie) => {
        if (movie.id === match.params.id) {
            selectedMovie = movie;
        }
    }

    setMovie(selectedMovie); 
    console.log(selectedMovie); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I tried something similar to this previously as well but couldn't get it to work. I used a regular for loop and tried to match movie id with params id.

Comment: A regular loop should work just as well, so you mush have had a small bug :)